# why files not delete for maxDateRollBackups settings

Tags: log4net

I have below log4Net configuration,

```
<appender name="WhateverYouNameThis" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <threshold value="All" />
    <file value="logs\WhateverYouNameThisFile.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maxDateRollBackups value="2" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
    <maximumFileSize value="2KB" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd-HH.lo\g" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p - %m%n" />
    </layout>
 </appender>
```

**"maxSizeRollBackups =2"** works fine. When file gets larger than 2KB, it will roll to another file, up to 2 times, and then these will start getting **deleted** too if it goes over 2 files.

but **"maxDateRollBackups=2"** is not working. Any files older than 2 days is **not deleted**. Please suggest the reason!

When date change the file rename with 1 day before date, but files older than 2 days is not delete,

[image]

Comment: To future readers:
This question is also posted at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/496cf10e-8b7c-44aa-aea2-df10e72c3046/why-files-not-delete-for-maxdaterollbackups-settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems known in log4net. These issues https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-27 / https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-367 describes the major problems with the rolling file appender. If you have any new information, I am interested in solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
<appender name="AppLog"  type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:/Log/Applog/AppLog_" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <appendToFile value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd_HH'.log'" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
  <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern
      value="%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [%level] [%thread]: %message (%type{1}.%method.%line)%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<!--<appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-10date{HH:mm:ss}: %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>-->

<root>
  <level value="All" />
  <!--<appender-ref ref="Console" />-->
  <appender-ref ref="All" />
</root>

<logger additivity="false" name="AppLog">
  <level value="All"/>
  <appender-ref ref="AppLog" />
</logger>
```

Hope this helps :)

Uli